# How do I switch opened windows within the same application using shortcuts?

Tags: macos, shortcut, switching

As shown in the figure below, I opened three Safais windows. To switch among them, I double click the Safari ico in the dock and select the window.

[image]

**Is there any shortcuts to move these opened windows?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Command + ~
```

This switches windows of the app. Like Alt-Tab to switch application, this switches the windows of the selected app.

Comment: Perfect. Thx for pointing out this.

Comment: It's not tilde ~ it's backtick ` Just because shift/backtick to reverse the direction is tilde on most English keyboards doesn't mean it will always be.